# Get store code, not store view code

Tags: magento2, store-view, store-code

Using the `StoreManagerInterface` I am getting the current store via `$store = $this->storeManager->getStore()`.

I then want to get the code of the store. However, when using `$store->getCode()` I get the code of the store *view*, not the store.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
){
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function foo()
{
    echo $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode(); // returns store view code
}
```

Is there any way to just get the code of the *store*, not the *store view*?

Comment: @SureshChikani It was already in the original post. Nevertheless I have added a more precise example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For store group you can use

```
$this->storeManager->getGroup()->getCode();
```

Comment: Thx :). Didn't know that this was called a "group".